# No mouse or keyboard when booting ubuntu 12.04, 14.04, 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard, mouse

When I boot my machine the keyboard and mouse are totally irresponsive.  Yet, it does not happen at every boot, only on most boots.

I then restart the machine (often several times) until it starts in a different state and the mouse and keyboard become responsive.  I am clueless as to why my mouse and keyboard work only sometimes.

My machine is a Toshiba Satellite c670/c670d laptop, I am using the default in-built keyboard and (synaptics) mouse.

Any logical solutions welcome.

Comment: Wait, this is pretty hard to understand.  Is your mouse/keyboard switched off on a laptop?  Is it an external mouse/keyboard (or just the inbuilt mouse/keyboard of the laptop)? What do you mean by switched off? Do you mean that it does not give characters when typed or the mouse does not move.

Comment: Just the internal mouse/keyboard, and because the machine is therefore totally unresponsive the only option is to switch off and then on again.

Comment: That is much more likely a BIOS/UEFI/hardware problem, than kernel.  And definitely incredibly difficult to debug.  Nevertheless, the first thing i'd try is to repeatedly enter the BIOS/UEFI menu (across reboots) and see if I can replicate the issue inside that menu.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question to make it easier to comprehend?

Comment: Sometimes when I start the machine there is no pointer movement or keyboard response.  After switching off and then on again, usually twice more, the pointer will work as will the keyboard.

Comment: OK, I clarified it a little so we shall not have "question clearness" points anymore.  Yet (1) I'd really like you to test the BIOS/UEFI menu, and (2) the output of `dmesg` will be very useful (of course, we can only get that when the keyboard is working).